# Will linux rsync boost pictures copying speed with option --compress

Tags: rsync

I noticed that there is an option `--compress` of rsync tool in linux. Provided I need to copy millions of pictures from one directory to the other on the same computer. Will I benefit from this compression option or not ? Is compressing a good strategy to copy small pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I don't know what exactly you mean by "small pictures", but I am guessing that they are already compressed in some standard image format, e.g. JPEG or PNG. In that case, `--compress` will take time, but give no benefit in compression.